# What exactly does the --names-only option of apt-cache do?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

According to the manual, it

```
   search regex...
       search performs a full text search on all available package lists
       for the POSIX regex pattern given, see regex(7). It searches the
       package names and the descriptions for an occurrence of the regular
       expression and prints out the package name and the short
       description, including virtual package names. If --full is given
       then output identical to show is produced for each matched package,
       and if --names-only is given then the long description is not
       searched, only the package name is.
[...]

   --names-only, -n
       Only search on the package names, not the long descriptions.
       Configuration Item: APT::Cache::NamesOnly.
```

However, I came across a strange situation:

```
$ apt-cache search --names-only 'kde*' | grep tkcv
tkcvs - Graphical front-end to CVS and Subversion
```

Why in the world would the command above match `tk8.6-doc`? [Braiam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/41104/braiam) and I spent a few minutes chatting about this and he noticed that

```
$ apt-cache show tkcvs | grep -i kd
Replaces: tkdiff
Provides: tkdiff
```

So, Braiam suggested that it's matching the `Replaces` field as well which makes a certain amount of sense in the case of changing package names. OK then, but what about:

```
$ apt-cache search --names-only 'kde*' | grep tk8.6
tk8.6-doc - Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11, v8.6 - manual pages
$ apt-cache show tk8.6-doc | grep -i kd
Provides: tkdoc
Conflicts: tkdoc
```

Here it is either matching the `Conflicts` or the `Provides` fields and I can't twist the meaning of `--names-only` to make it match those fields. So, what exactly does `--names-only` search through? Is it the **names** of all **packages** that are mentioned in a package's description? It is clearly not matching the package name alone.

Comment: If I have to guess it's matching the virtual package name, and since apt-cache doesn't handle well the virtual packages it shows you the one with higher version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that `apt-cache search --names-only` also searches for `Provides`.  The man page needs to be updated.  [Here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=618017) is a link to the bug report regarding the same.

> As per bug #98695¹, it seems that "apt-cache search --names-only" is
>   also looking into "Provides" field while man page suggests that only
>   package name is queried.
>
> I think the manual page of apt-cache should be updated accordingly to
>   reflect the current state of the paremeter.
>
> ¹http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=98695

[This](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=98695) was the wishlist that caused the behavior of `apt-cache search` to be changed to search `Provides` in addition to the package name.

Comment: I think you've nailed it. Every case I can find seems to be matching against a Provides field. I'll give it a little while longer and come back and accept. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon You question prompted to hunt for this.  I've myself wondered about the issue you reported a couple of times earlier, but didn't really chase it.

Comment: Jesus, why would they wish for something like that... why wouldn't they add a new --names-and-provides-only parameter, or ANY other way...